# Windows 7 window manager that resizes based on focus

Tags: window-manager, windows-7

I'm looking for something like a tiling window manager, but not exactly. All the tiling managers I've seen have very similar behavior: windows snap to a square of screen real estate, and stay there. I don't think I could work with the smaller window sizes that that produces - I like my windows to be taking up more screen estate than that when I'm working on them. I also highly dislike full screen windows (I need to switch apps a lot and have a Mac background), so simply maximizing whatever I'm working on from it's tiled position isn't an great answer either.

What I'm looking for is something closer to OSX's Expose. I want to see every window I have open on a given monitor (ideally as a zoomed out window, but as icons, tiles, or just really small windows works too), but have it restore to its normal size when it becomes active, and return to being a tile when I switch away.

[image: Example manager]

Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: I am *thrilled* at finally having a site for these types of questions.  Yay!

Answer (score 4):

I have a Logitech Wave keyboard that has a button that does exactly what you are looking for. When the keyboard is installed and Windows 7/8 Aero is enabled it will flash all open windows into a Tiled view similar to Mac Mission Control (New name for Expose,) and you can click a given tile to bring that window to the front. If you Maximize all your windows and use the tiles to select the window you want than it will do exactly what you want.

Unfortunately, it is flaky with multiple monitors.

Good luck!

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-wave-combo-mk550

Settings for Application Switcher in Setpoint software. Apparently Setpoint 4.8 functioned correctly on multiple monitors but I have not tried myself.:
[image]

View of Application Switcher "Tile View":
[image]

Comment: not *exactly* a software rec but sounds like a good match despite that. I'd strongly suggest  including a link and an exact version.

Comment: Thank you Nick; I was not aware I could post links and pictures.

No, its not Exactly a software rec, but it is in a round about way :D

Comment: looking like a high quality rec now :)

Comment: Ooh, nice recommendation!  I'm not sure buying a keyboard will work for me, since it's for my work computer, but it did get me thinking about Expose/Mission Control-type software.  My preference would be for the "Tile view" to be the default state, but having to hit a key or key combo to call it up isn't the end of the world.